# Issue related to CAN protocol? do I need to use CAN?

Tags: can-bus

We are building Electric Vehicle for Formula students competition, for communication protocol between modules we have to use CAN method. Do we need every module to know data from the other modules. For eg. we are using Micro-controller raspberry pi Pico to collect data from sensor and based on data perform action by same microcontroller itself. But CAN method says that data should be routed and shared in network where other receiver would collect. so one thing we thought was to use one microcontroller to collect data from all sensor and share data with CAN controller to another micro-controller to perform the action. But it is increase in complexity, and CAN was designed to reduce complexity. so I am confused how to apply CAN protocol. I am not getting when some data where it is collected can be used then why do we have to share. Or may be i am just going wrong so please help to clarify this concept. thank you.

Comment: "and CAN was designed to reduce complexity"  Err, not at all. It was designed to be rugged and reliable. It can get quite complex, especially when you look at the various application layers like CANopen or DeviceNet.

Answer (score 4):

CAN Bus and the upper layer protocols based on it (like CANopen) generally provide a messaging medium for **publisher & subscriber** pattern.

- Publisher Nodes: They produce data and publish this data to the bus.
  Sensor nodes are good examples of publisher nodes.
- Subscriber Nodes: They subscribe to one or more data packages on the
  bus and consume these data. For example, a motor driver may subscribe
  to some speed command and drive the motor accordingly.

A node can both produce and consume data, acting as a publisher and a subscriber at the same time. For example, the main control unit in the car can read various sensor data from the bus, process them and publish command data for the actuator nodes (like motor drivers).

When using CAN Bus, instead of inventing your own protocol, it may be a better idea to use an existing protocol, like *CANopen*. I suggest you to read *CiA 301* document which explains the fundamentals of CANopen. Even if you don't use it, it will give you some ideas.